# opencv characters void segmentation

Tags: opencv

i use this functions to segment characters image ,but the programme crach ,somone can help me please to found solution why it crach?

Comment: Can you run it in debug mode and tell us which line is crashing, please? Which os and compiler are you using?

Comment: i use Qt creator to compile ,but i think i don't have a compilation problem because when i try just the five first lines it execute the SetImageROI ,but when i add the code of CvFindContours it crach ,so i think i have problem in the code of contour

Comment: If this question has been successfully answered, consider selecting the official answer by clicking on the checkbox near it. If not, consider adding your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pinpoint the line that causes the crash. For that I can think in 2 ways:

- Use a debugger;
- or if you are afraid of that, use the `printf()` method:

The `printf()` method involves placing a `printf()` call after each function call in your program, so when you run your application you can see in the console what was the last `printf()` message. That will help you locate the code that is responsible for the crash. Example:

```
printf("dbg10\n");

IplImage *img_cv = cvLoadImage("plaque.jpg");
printf("dbg20\n");

cvSetImageROI(img_cv,cvRect(8,10,60,35));
printf("dbg30\n");

IplImage *img_pl = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img_cv),img_cv->depth,img_cv->nChannels);
printf("dbg40\n");

cvCopy(img_cv,img_pl, NULL);
printf("dbg50\n");

cvResetImageROI(img_cv);
printf("dbg60\n");

//etc
```

From what I saw in your code, the first 2 calls have the potential to crash your application: if `cvLoadImage()` fails to load an image it will return a NULL pointer. Since the next function receives the pointer as a parameter, it will try to dereference the null pointer and that can a crash. Solution? **Always check the *freaking* return of the calls you make**:

```
IplImage *img_cv = cvLoadImage("plaque.jpg");
if (!img_cv)
{
   printf("Failed to load image.\n");
   exit(1);
}

cvSetImageROI(img_cv,cvRect(8,10,60,35));
```

Comment: The printf calls are just to give you a hint of where the crash is happening, it will not fix the problem.